# Como criar (spawn) vários retangulos?

Tags: java

Estou criando um joguinho *Jframe* onde eu preciso criar vários retângulos que serão os **projeteis/balas** do meu **personagem(main/principal)** então eu criei a seguinte classe:

**Classe Balas**

```
package dannark;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class balas {
    int x,y,lar,alt;
    String dir;

    public balas(int x, int y, int lar, int alt, String dir){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.lar = lar;
        this.alt = alt;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics bbg){
        if(dir.equals("right")){
            x += 10;
        }else{
            x -= 10;
        }
        bbg.setColor(Color.yellow);
        bbg.fillRect(main.camX+x,  main.camY+y, lar, alt);
    }
}
```

Mais como eu posso chama-la na minha classe principal de forma que quando eu pressione o botão **C** Ela dispare sempre uma nova bolinha?

**Classe Main**

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_C){
            //o que fazer aqui para spawnar varios novos retangulos?
        }

    }
```

Comment: Em que pacote está a classe Main? Você conseguiu sobrescrever o método `keyPressed()` corretamente?

Comment: no pacote dannark, Mas Na verdade voce não precisa se basear no meu código, eu apenas precisaria de uma `luz` de como fazer isso para que eu possa adaptar eu mesmo posteriormente :) Os codigos que eu mostrei acima eram pra ser exemplos mas acho que eu compliquei um pouco.

Comment: OBS A keyPressed() Funciona perfeitamente o probçema é que do jeito que eu fiz eu consigo atirar apenas um projetil por vez...

Comment: Quantos projéteis deveria atirar? Não seria o caso de fazer um `for`?

Comment: o quanto for necessario, cada vez que eu preciono eu atiro 1 vez, mas se o usuario precionar 100 veses em um segundo por exemplo, eu queria q saissem 100 projeteis. Se fosse o caso do for como seria?

Comment: Agora estou entendendo, mas acho estranho não atirar vários. Você consegue dizer qual é o "limite" de bolinhas que atira? Exemplo: se apertar 2 vezes em um segundo está ok, mais que isso dá pau. O `for` eu sugeri quando ainda não tinha entendido bem sua pergunta, esquece.

Comment: Não veja bem, por enquanto eu nao gostaria de impor limites.. o problema é que eu nao sei como desenhar mais de um retangulo... Ou seja Eu Instanceio a classe balas: **balas bala = new balas(x,y-25,6,3,direcao);** e depois em algum lugar eu desenho ela **bala.draw(main.bbg);** e quando eu preciono **C** eu seto a posição para o mega.x e mega.y que é o meu personagem principal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15340/discussion-between-dannark-and-math).

Answer (score 1):

Ei pessoal Consegui descobrir uma solução, bastava usar uma arraylist para armazenar minhas diversas instancias da minha mesma classe. Esse site aqui me ajudou:
http://www.guj.com.br/java/75460-instanciar-objetos-dinamicamente

**Ou seja 1ª criei a array:**

```
   ArrayList<balas> bala = new ArrayList();
```

**2ª Depois salvei as instancias dentro da array**

```
  if(shoot){
      bala.add(new balas(x,y-25,6,3,direcao)); // instancia um novo Objeto e salvo na array
  }
```

**3ª E para pegar o valor de cada uma era so fazer assim:**

```
  for(int i = 0; i < bala.size(); i++){
      bala.get(i).draw(main.bbg);
  }
```

O resultado foi:

[image: Multiplos shoots]